# Access MongoDB using my server public IP Address

Tags: mongodb

I am currently hosting MongoDB on my VPS server, installed with ubuntu 16.04. The installation of MongoDb on it was successful. I could access the database from SSH using 127.0.0.1 `$ mongo 127.0.0.1`

I have then downloaded mongoDB client from https://studio3t.com on my local mac book laptop. I actually wanted to access the mongodb on my server using the mongodb client which is locally installed on my machine. I supply my server IP Address and the default mongodb port to the mongodb client like this, IP: `69.36.180.00` port: `27017` this however gives the below error

```
         Connection failed.
   SERVER [69.36.180.00:27017] (Type: UNKNOWN) 
 |_/ Connection error (MongoSocketOpenException): Exception opening socket
|____/ Socket error: Connection refused (Connection refused)

Details:
Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches      
ReadPreferenceServerSelector{readPreference=primary}. Client view of 
cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=69.36.180.00:27017,
 type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception= {com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by
{java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)}}]
```

I however decided to access mongodb from the SSH terminal on the server itself using this `$ mongo  69.36.180.00` it also didn't allow it access, below is the error that was shown on the terminal

```
   MongoDB shell version v3.4.5
   connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/69.36.180.00
 2017-06-22T11:35:16.300+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: Failed to 
 parse mongodb:// URL: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/69.36.180.00 :
 connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:237:13
 @(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

I really read around these errors, some suggested I uncomment the `bindIP` found in `mongod.conf`, others suggest I allow firewall access on the port, I have done all these but to no avail.

I would be grateful if someone could share an idea as to how to deal with this. Regards

Comment: Narrow it down..
Check if firewall is the issue: `telnet 69.36.180.00 27017` if telnet is not successful, then it's surely a firewall issue. 
If telnet is successful, then you may look at bindIp, etc.

Comment: @acsrujan I think using `telnet 69.36.180.00 27017` gives this error `Trying 69.36.180.00...
telnet: connect to address 69.36.180.00: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host`

Comment: That tells firewall is indeed the issue here. Can you verify AWS Security group associated has a rule saying 27017 is allowed from your IP address?

Comment: Yes, I have done that it worked. Thanks @acsrujan